# Header Footer and content

Tags: sapui5

I already create view : header, content, and footer but footer and content not display and not getting an error. the directory in form1.view.xml is correct because no error when I load the form1 view. when I command the header code and I refresh, the content show and footer still not show. when I command the header and content, the footer show. how to fix this problem?

Form1.view.xml

```
<App id="navCon"
    class="footer-height footer-color header-color background-home background-color
                            footer-size-color panel-header">

    <!-- Header -->
    <mvc:XMLView viewName="sap.ui.taspen.taspen.Header" />

    <App>
        <pages>
            <Page>
                <Panel id="panelModule" headerText="Header form" class="panelForm">
                    <content>
                        <Label text="Ini form 1" />
                    </content>
                </Panel>
            </Page>
        </pages>
    </App>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <mvc:XMLView viewName="sap.ui.taspen.taspen.Footer" />
</App>
```

Header:

```
<mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:t="sap.ui.table" xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout" xmlns:tnt="sap.tnt"
    controllerName="sap.ui.taspen.taspen.Header" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <App>
        <pages>
            <Page showHeader="false">
                <tnt:ToolHeader>
                    <html:img src="icon/logo_taspen.png" class="header-logo-taspen" />
                    <html:p class="text-header">NEW APPLICATION CORE BUSINESS</html:p>
                    <ToolbarSpacer width="20px" />

                    <tnt:ToolHeaderUtilitySeparator />
                    <ToolbarSpacer>
                        <layoutData>
                            <OverflowToolbarLayoutData priority="NeverOverflow"
                                minWidth="20px" />
                        </layoutData>
                    </ToolbarSpacer>

                    <Text text="Selasa, 21/4/2017 / 11:07 AM" class="text-white" />
                    <Text text="Hello, Jhon Doe" class="text-white">
                        <layoutData>
                            <OverflowToolbarLayoutData priority="NeverOverflow" />
                        </layoutData>
                    </Text>

                    <Button icon="sap-icon://log" type="Reject" press="logoutPress"
                        class="button-logout button-logout-icon margin-logout">
                        <layoutData>
                            <OverflowToolbarLayoutData priority="NeverOverflow" />
                        </layoutData>
                    </Button>
                </tnt:ToolHeader>
            </Page>
        </pages>
    </App>
</mvc:View>
```

Footer:

```
<mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:t="sap.ui.table" xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout" xmlns:tnt="sap.tnt"
    controllerName="sap.ui.taspen.taspen.Footer" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <App>
        <Page showHeader="false">
            <footer>
                <OverflowToolbar id="otbFooter">
                    <Button type="Transparent" text="Kebijakan dan Privasi"
                        press="kebdanprivPress" />
                    <Button type="Transparent" text="Bantuan" press="bantuanPress" />
                    <ToolbarSpacer />
                    <Label text="All Rights Reserved PT. Taspen Persero" />
                    <html:img src="icon/copyright-symbol.png" class="footer-logo-copyright" />
                    <Label text="2018" />
                </OverflowToolbar>
            </footer>
        </Page>
    </App>
</mvc:View>
```

Answer (score 1):

To Display custome header instead of page header you have to use

```
<customHeader></customHeader>
```

tag.and remaining you have to place in `<content></content>`tag. can see you are missing content tag.